# Origin of the "Millennium" tv-series

Tags: the-girl-with-the-dragon-tattoo, millennium-trilogy

I've already checked out [IMDb.com](https://www.imdb.com/?ref_=nv_home) about my question, but didn't get a clear answer and even got more confused about it. I'm wondering whether the "[Millennium](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1634549/?ref_=tt_rec_tt)" tv-series is based on the previous trilogy of the movies that were made in 2009, or if the tv-series is independent, and made entirely from scratch?

For example, when I open the "[The Girl Who Played with Fire](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1216487/?ref_=tt_rec_tt)" movie page on [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/?ref_=nv_home), and scroll down to see its duration, I see that the runtime is "129 min | 183 min (TV)".

The first time is for the original movie, but what about the second one? What does "183 min (TV)" mean? Does this runtime include the "[Millennium](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1634549/?ref_=tt_rec_tt)" tv-series? Does this mean the "[Millennium](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1634549/?ref_=tt_rec_tt)" tv-series was created from the original and deleted scenes of the original movies that were cut from the movies? Or was the entire tv-series shot from scratch, and didn't the creators use any shots or scenes from the original trilogy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean "Millennium" tv-series was created from the original and deleted scenes of the original movies that didn't use for the movies

## Yes

As explained on [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(miniseries))

> The Millennium TV miniseries is a compilation of the three Swedish film adaptations, *The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo, The Girl Who Played with Fire,* and *The Girl Who Kicked the Hornets' Nest* with **extended scenes,** adding more depth in both the stories and the characters.
>
> It was divided into 6 episodes total, with each episode of the series about 90 minutes long, making the television series about 110 minutes longer than the movies.